# Excluding Empty Edges When Morph Closing Lines In An Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

How to connect disjoint vertical lines in an image without expanding them over the outer margin area?

*Input image (simplified example) :*

[image: Input Image Example]

*Using `Morph Close` operation :*

```
inputImg = cv2.imread(imgPath)
grayInput = cv2.cvtColor(inputImg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thre = cv2.inRange(grayInput, 0, 155)

closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thre, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((500,1), np.uint8))
```

*Current output :*

[image: Current output]

*Desired output :*

[image: Desired output]

**P.S.** I could just add margin that is greater than the closing kernel but this would be memory inefficient due to the large size of the production images. Production images have important amount of lines with random gaps as well.

Comment: Are the end of the lines always at (approximately) the top and the bottom of the images?

Comment: @stateMachine sometimes the (broken) lines are in the middle of the image with large space around them. An ideal solution would connect every TWO broken parts, so it will exclude parts that are at the extremities with no other part to connect with.

Comment: Try identifying each line segment (connected component analysis will do), then find their coordinates. Figure out which lines to join by comparing coordinates, then draw the completed lines.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @CrisLuengo I just experimented a bit with connected components and it seems reliable even with some edge cases. How come there's no official python documentation for them? Are the classes and methods same as c++ ?

Comment: I don’t think the Python bindings for OpenCV add anything, the C++ documentation also contains the Python call syntax for each function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binarize your image, find the columns that contain white pixels, then connect the lines between the lowest and highest white pixels in each column.

The below code will accomplish this. I explained it with comments.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("xoxql.png") # Load the image
img = (img < 255).all(axis=2) # Binarize the image
rows, cols = img.nonzero() # Get all nonzero indices
unique_cols = np.unique(cols) # Select columns that contain nonzeros
for col_index in unique_cols: # Loop through the columns
    start = rows[col_index == cols].min() # Select the lowest nonzero row index
    end = rows[col_index == cols].max() # Select the highest nonzero row index
    img[start:end, col_index] = True # Set all "pixels" to True between the lowest and highest row indices
img = img * np.uint8(255) # Multiply by 255 to convert the matrix back to an image
cv2.imwrite("result.png", img) # Save the image
```

[image]

The lines on the right side of your image are not exactly lined up, which will leave some gaps on the edges.